# Third party tools for managing a text file size

Tags: c#, .net, filesize

I need to manage a text file upto 5gb size. I'd like to keep the file under 5gb with new text being added to the end of the file and text at the beginning of the file being removed.
I know from code i can do similar to this

```
FileInfo txtfile = new FileInfo(nameOfFile);
if (txtfile.Length > sizelimit)     
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(nameOfFile).Skip(10).ToArray();  
    File.WriteAllLines(nameOfFile, lines);
}
```

but i am looking for some third party tools that can perform this type of operations efficiently with performance. Windows Event Logs work this way.
Can anyone please suggest some third party libraries which i can use.

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines` for a 5 GB file is a pretty interesting solution.

Comment: @dymanoid thats why i am asking for any libraries

Comment: Quite sure that windows event logs aren't stored in text files. You are allowed to write logs to the windows event log system yourself, by the way

Comment: @dymanoid you can't easily and quickly remove entries from the start of the file though. Better to use a proper logging solution. nLog, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0 etc

Comment: ps; "Questions asking us to find a library, tool, blog, document or external resource are off topic..."